# Jenkins decrease in performance when moves to kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I'm doing a POC of moving Jenkins to kubernetes on GKE all is fine and well but now that I look at the time each JOB is executing that's kinda unacceptable
on VM timer for some jobs were `1.5min, 10.5min, 3.5min` on kubernetes with jenkins agent (with 8cpus and 14gb ram to which he never gets to) it's `5min, 35min, 6.5min` any thought on how to improve the performance or why is it happening? It's just as normal computing space as the previous VM, cpu/ram ain't the issue cause agent have plenty of it.

Comment: So you confirm, that you have plenty of free resources (CPU/MEMORY)? What thoses jobs does? Did you customize your config to GKE or its not necessary in your case? Could you share your job yaml or did you use there `activeDeadlineSeconds`?

Comment: well downloading java code and running some tests have the most impact on execution time; most of stuff had to be configured for GKE - jenkins agent image Dockerfile etc. ; I have no idea what this option does `activeDeadlineSeconds` so haven't used it